# XMLDocument.Load(url) through a proxy

Tags: c#, xml, proxy

I have a bit of code that basically reads an XML document using the XMLDocument.Load(uri) method which works fine, but doesn't work so well if the call is made through a proxy.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to make this call (or achieve the same effect) through a proxy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have to provide credentials to the proxy?

If so, this should help:
"Supplying Authentication Credentials to XmlResolver when Reading from a File"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720674.aspx

Basically, you...

1. Create an XmlTextReader using the URL
2. Set the Credentials property of the reader's XmlResolver
3. Create an XmlDocument instance and pass the reader to the Load method.

Answer (score 14):

This is the code that I ended up using:

```
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(Settings.Default.ProxyAddress);
wp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Default.ProxyUsername, Settings.Default.ProxyPassword);
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = wp;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));
XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(ms);
return XDocument.Load(rdr);
```

Answer (score 12):

Use lomaxx's answer but change

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));
XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(url);
```

to

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url));
XmlTextReader rdr = new XmlTextReader(ms);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't configure XMLDocument to use proxy. You can use WebRequest or WebClient class to load data via proxy and pass obtained response stream to XMLDocument

Also you can try to use XmlTextReader class. It allows you set network credentials. For details see:

[Supplying Authentication Credentials to XmlResolver when Reading from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720674.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [WebProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy(VS.80).aspx) and WebRequest to download the xml, then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually rather than storing in settings for your app, you can use the Windows proxy config. I believe this is standard now so not having to configure proxy in each program i.e. look at Chrome's Settings for Proxy directs to Windows

```
IWebProxy wp = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();                  
wp.Credentials = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy().Credentials;                    
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = wp;
```