# UrlEncode adds current working directory to my URL

Tags: c#, urlencode

I am debugging my C# ASP.NET website that grabs XML content from a different server then parses it.

**My Problem:** Because I am running my website locally I cannot access the XML from the url.

When I go to call:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.load( Server.UrlEncode("http://www.website.com/test.aspx") );
```

It places the current working directory infront of the URL so it becomes...

```
xdoc.load( "C:/users/Visual_Studio/http://www.website.com/test.aspx" );
```

This obviously means it doesn't get the xml file contents.

**How can I stop this from occurring? Am I meant to use Url.PathEncode() or something? I am running/debugging my project locally on my computer so its not running from the server**

Comment: I've never seen that behavior from `UrlEncode`. Do you have a helper method that might be causing it?

Comment: why do you want to use `URLEncode` unless you have (potentially dangerous) `QueryStrings`?

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124932/xmldocument-loadurl-through-a-proxy

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the xdoc.Load method is expecting a URL to start with "http://" or some other protocol. The URL encoded form of the URL you are providing appears to the Load function to be a file name.

I would be surprised if this worked in a production environment either. To make this work, just pass the URL on to the Load function. If you have arguments that you'll need to append to the URL then those may need to be URL encoded.