# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized (when trying to access repository svn)

Tags: c#, asp.net, svn

I want to use a file that is in my svn repository as follows:

```
     public List <XElement> TableReqDAL (string file)
     {


         XDocument xml = XDocument.Load ("http://source:8080/svn/DataWarehouse/MEX/trunk/TSO/Mappings/" + file + ".xml");
        (...)

     }
```

I get this error:

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: as error says, you don't have permission to access the file, so it looks like you need to authorize before getting the file. Is that file served by IIS?

Comment: have you an idea about how to configure permission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this thread,

[XMLDocument.Load(url) through a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124932/xmldocument-loadurl-through-a-proxy)

You're going to need to authenticate before you can access the resource - try browsing to the URL in your browser, you are going to be presented with a username\password dialog - you need to do this programmatically.

Comment: it's ok about recovering login and pwd but how I can use it (what's the configuration that I must do it after recovering login and pwd)to consume a file from my repository ?